How can I run a security scan on an Azure ARM Image?
I've got packer building Azure VM images published to my Compute Gallery (sig) and terraform setting up an image-test resource group with a VM created off of the image.
I want to run a security scan as a part of my test and I've been trying to work with Defender for Cloud but it seems to act on a subscription and I want to limit this to a resource group to limit the impact.

Can you provide more details of what you mean by "ARM Image", is this a container image, VM image?

Sure, Same, by this I mean an VM image that I published to a compute gallery (sig)

updated for clarity
